# Output of Perl Script isn't being rendered

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, perl

I have a client using "FormMail.pl", which I believe is taken from some perl repository around the net.  We recently migrated her site to a new server and this script stopped working.  I found a few items that weren't configured on the new Apache installation, and I now have the script running... but the HTML output isn't being rendered and the "Location:" redirect is also not working.  Again -- the script worked fine on the old server.

```
print "Location: $safeConfig{'redirect'}\n\n";
```

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```

Both of these statements just put something like "Location: thankYou.html" on the screen rather than any content.  The HTML is not rendered.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I'd beware of FormMail.pl scripts - the last time I was looking at them (admittedly a few years ago) they were notoriously insecure and tended to become spammer magnets.

Comment: Is any other Perl rendered on this site at all? Sounds like an issue there?

Answer (score 1):

There's a danger you have a notorious piece of poor code from Matt Wright's Script Archive.
Replace it with the equivalent from http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like:

AddHandler cgi-script .pl

in your Apache config file?